# String reverse app not working- index outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays

So, I've just started learning C#, and to be honest — I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm trying to make a string reverse app, and iv'e come up with this code:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char[] wordArray = input.ToCharArray();
for(int i = input.Length; i >= 0; --i)
{
    Console.Write(wordArray[i]);
}
```

I've checked a bunch of different tutorials and documentations, and as far as I can tell from most of them, this should work, but it doesn't.

Whenever I run the app, I type in the word I want to reverse, and the app crashes. It shows an error that say "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I found better ways to reverse strings online using Array.Reverse(), but i would still like to understand why this error occurred. Like I said before, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing, and I'll be happy if anyone can explain this in layman's terms.

Comment: start from `input.Length-1`

Comment: `for(int i = input.Length-1; i >= 0; --i)` arrays indexes starts in 0 and goes to lenght -1

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is here `int i = input.Length;`. Your array is starting from 0 index and the last element is on index `input.Length-1`. So when you start from `input.Lenght` you are going out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'array' (a group of elements) contains each of the characters in your string.

Each of these elements can be accessed by its index, which starts at `0`. So for the word `word` you would have:

```
0: 'w'
1: 'o'
2: 'r'
3: 'd'
```

The `Length` of this array is 4 - it has 4 elements - but you can see that the largest index isn't 4, it's 3.

Your loop counts from 4 down to 0 (as its `Length` is 4). When attempting to access the element with index 4, it throws the exception 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'.

The explanation as to how this works above should make this error message self-explanatory: 4 is outside the bounds of 0 to 3. You should start your loop from `3`, which is `input.Length - 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
string s = "123";
            string r = "";
            foreach (char c in s) r = c + r;
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: OP says he knows better ways to reverse the string. What was asked was why the particular solution produced an error - this answer does not address the question.